# Add activity node android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I understand an activity needs to be defined/described in the AndroidManifest xml file.

I do not understand why this does not work as many of the tutorials say it should.

If I start a new android project in eclipse running on ubuntu 11.10. Then add a new class derived off (extends) android.app.Activity - then click on AndroidManifest.xml file in the package explorer -
I can see the Application nodes box and the Add button. My problem is that when I press the Add button (to add a new element) a dialog pops up that is EMPTY. There is no selection for an elements and the OK button is greyed out.

Furthermore, I cannot type a name here either, only press cancel. Why is this box not populating with selections? I have tried reinstalling from scratch and double checked version dependencies and permissions and I cannot find anything questionable. For now - I will add the xml tag manually but, I would like to know why it is not working properly. Anyone have an Idea?

Comment: Please post your code, guessing your problem isn't fun.

Comment: The problem has something to do with Eclipse. The code builds fine with no errors. The second class is identical to the generated one except it has a different name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you extend Activity and import android.app.Activity like this:

```
import android.app.Activity;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Then try going to Project -> Clean menus on eclipse.

If that doesnt help try right clicking your project and click refresh.

And if it still doesnt show the activity on AndroidManifest, manually add the following line on the XML after making appropriate changes

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity"></activity>
```

Hope that helps. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - unfortunately for me even after a refresh and clean menu, it still does not work. I will add the tags by hand but, I wonder now what else isn't working properly in eclipse. This does not inspire confidence while learning something new. Thanks again.

Comment: i'm sorry to hear that you are having problems using eclipse. are you sure your android ADT is installed properly and sdk is also installed and used by eclipse? If nothing works, please backup your source codes, delete the current installation and try re-doing the things mentioned on this page -> http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

Comment: Thanks again. Yeah, I have recreated everything from start - even the source. It does not work and I gave up on why. Perhaps I will ditch eclipse and just hand code it from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your src directory isn't defined as source directory in project properties (build path)?
This could be the reason why your classes don't show up in the dialog.

Comment: They do show up in the dialog, that is not the problem. When I open the AndroidManifest.xml file in the eclipse package explorer - I press the "add" button to add a node in the application nodes. A dialog pops up that says "Create a new element at the top level, in Application" There is a box under it and a BLANK list. The OK button is greyed, It does not matter what I type in the textbox. ALL I can do is press cancel. Should there not be node types to select in the empty box? (Activity for instance?) It is like the xml file is not being parsed correctly but, It is generated, not edited.